# implementing insertbefore() in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show error messages below an array of textboxes that I have selected using Javascript. The error messages are being put by creating a new span element and using the insertBefore() method. The span element is created in the function since I don't want to hard code it into the DOM. The span messages do show but each time I submit the form, they are appended over and over again. I'd like to show the span messages only once and each time the form is submitted, they are shown once only. Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="1" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="2" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="3" class="textbox" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
    // var span = document.createElement('span');
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('.textbox');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++ )
        {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            (function(index)
            {
                span.innerHTML = 'error ' + index;
                inputs[index].parentNode.insertBefore(span, inputs[index].nextElementSibling);
            })(i);
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

Each time I submit, I'd like the error messages to be shown below the textbox and not appended over and over again. They should be shown just once and I'd like to do this without using jQuery or any sort of library.

Comment: You shouldn't give NUMERICAL ids or names to elements, it's bad practice when it comes to code readability and backwards compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a check before you insert. Here is one way to do it.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        (function (index) {
            span.innerHTML = 'error ' + index;
            if (inputs[index].nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'SPAN')
                inputs[index].parentNode.insertBefore(span, inputs[index].nextElementSibling);
        })(i);
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewerite your example to create available 3 span tags instead of crate them in code. If there are some errors, populate them to span rather than creating/deleting the spans in code.

```js
    var slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('.textbox');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            (function (index) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('span')[index]
                .innerHTML = 'error ' + index;
            })(i);
        }
    }, false);
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow">
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" name="1" class="textbox" /><span></span>
            <input type="text" name="2" class="textbox" /><span></span>
            <input type="text" name="3" class="textbox" /><span></span>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'd not like to hard code them in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for page to be load, the you should run JavaScript.

PageLoad Event : window.onload=function(){}

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                (function (index) {
                    span.innerHTML = 'error ' + index;
                    inputs[index].parentNode.insertBefore(span, inputs[index].nextElementSibling);
                })(i);
            }
        }, false);
    }  
</script>
```

Put your code in window.onload event.